# What's wrong with my usage of Azure Alerts?

Tags: azure

OK, so I simply want to create an alert, for when my URL is unreachable.

As a test, I followed the steps found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability) to create an availability test for https://www.google.com, and as success criteria, I put 500 as my HTTP response; it was felt that this will trigger an alert.

The action group that I created is an MS Teams group; this is working, I know this because it is used by different alerts. Then, I created a new Alert, with the Condition of my newly created availability test, then I waited.

I expected to get an alert upon failure of my test. I can see that the test is failing, but there is no alert. What might I [not be grasping/be doing wrong]?

Comment: How exactly is the alert configured. What is the Frequency of evaluation and the aggregation period?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The frequency is 1 minute. Where might I find aggregation period? and what does that refer to?

Comment: Actually I see aggregate now. I chose the default, which, if it hasn't changed, is 6 hours

Comment: Actually, I chose the default, which, if it hasn't changed, is 5 minutes

Comment: Hmm ok. What is the exact condition you used for the alert?

Comment: Signal name: Availability Test. Actually maybe I chose just 'Availability'. I will recreate that test.

Comment: No, I created my alert from scratch, I simply had to add my Action Group, the rest were defaults.

Comment: As in, I created my availability test, then viewed all Alerts, then clicked on the newly appearing availability test, adding my action group to the Actions section; then, in the 'Alert rule details', I entered nothing controversial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I must have mistyped something. All I know is that doing it from scratch (for the 3rd time) fixed it.